# Server 2008 - VirtualBox - WDS - PXE Booting Windows 7 - no file found

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, pxe-boot, wds, waik

I know this is a particularly difficult thing to troubleshoot as there are various complexities in the setup, but wondering if anyone has experienced this and can recognise the issue / offer some steps to troubleshoot.

Firstl, is WAIK required before you can use WDS for a capture?

I'm running virtualbox on a macbook pro.

Setup:

- Server 2008 Roles: DHCP, Active Directory, DC, WDS
- Windows 7 - receives DHCP from the PDC and receives DHCP upon PXE Boot

Both VMs have bridged adapters.

I have added windows 7 install and boot images and gone through the process of creating a Capture Image in preparation for the PXE Boot to capture the installed OS.

My Windows 7 virtualbox is set to network boot, it runs through the PXE Boot obtains DHCP but then states "No filename" and continues to boot off the hard disk.

Hope I have included all the information you will need to know! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ObNitPick: there's no PDC in 2008, just DCs...

Comment: my bad... running server standard 2008, as the DC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you configured DHCP options 66 and 67? 66 should be set to the WDS server and option 67 should be set to `boot\x86\wdsnbp.com`.

Comment: My DHCP server resides on the same server as my WDS so this is not required as I understand it?

Comment: This information was correct except the only one that would work was pxeboot.n12 re: option 67

Comment: Options 66 and 67 *should* only be necessary when running a DHCPd other than the Microsoft built-in one, or if WDS is on a different subnet than the DHCP server. That said, I've seen situations where it's still necessary even when it *should* work (the error indicates this exact scenario). Using "pxeboot.n12" for 67 will result in the client doing a basic PXE boot; if you've only got one WDS server this might work, but isn't how it's *supposed* to work.

Comment: Potentially because of the fact I'm doing this in VirtualBox, am not sure but without the DHCP options set I get no PXE boot.  Thanks for the help!